# can client of the xmpp server disconnect other client from the server?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

It this possible? How? (Maybe silly question, but I couldn't find answer :( )

EDIT:I am using Openfire server embedded into different system, so I need if admin of the system kicks out the user from the system server, user's connection to Openfire server should be closed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under some cases, yes :

- The same full jid "user@host/resource" connects from two different sources. The server usually disconnects the old one. Though some servers (OpenFire comes to mind) may make it configurable.
- If a client has admin right, using *adhoc* commands, it can destroy another connection. It depends on the server implementation. (ejabberd makes that possible)

In all other cases, clients are isolated and this can't happen. (Or it's a high priority bug in the server).

Comment: Also, if your client supports XEP-146 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0146.html) you can tell it to log off, without server authorization required.

Comment: @cstar what commands would those be? ejabberd does not support XEP-0146.

Answer (score 0):

In the Openfire admin console, running as an HTTP server on port 9090, the administrator can disconnect any connected client.